# How to do dynamic click events

Tags: angular

I have a question - how to dynamically change a function which is assigned to button? I would like to change the function in buttons after user chosed one option. Now I use `if` but I repeat my own code by changing a visibility. Can I have "question2" buttons only once and change what they will do dynamically?

I have tried:

```js
document.getElementById("id").setAttribute("click", "select(darkred)");
document.getElementById("id").setAttribute("onclick", "select(darkred)");
document.getElementById("id").setAttribute("(click)", "select(darkred)");
```

But they didn't work.

```html
<div name="question1">
  <button (click)="select('red')">Select Red</button>
  <button (click)="select('green')">Select Green</button>
</div>

<!-- The result of answer will change function which is assigned to next buttons -->

<div name="question2" [hidden]="isRed">
  <button (click)="select('lightred')">Select Light</button>
  <button (click)="select('darkred')">Select Dark</button>
</div>
<div name="question2" [hidden]="isGreen">
  <button (click)="select('lightgreen')">Select Light</button>
  <button (click)="select('darkgreen')">Select Dark</button>
</div>
```

App.component.ts:

```ts
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  isRed = true;
  isGreen = true;

  select(color: string) {
    if (color === 'red') {
      isRed = false;
      isGreen = true;
    }
    if (color === 'green') {
      isRed = true;
      isGreen = false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: try something like this (in your Component) `document.getElementById('xyz').addEventListener("click", () => { this. select(darkred) })`, because "onclick" wont bind the component function. Therefore you have to use (click), but you cant do it with setAttribute i guess.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

```html
<div name="question1">
  <button (click)="selectBaseColor('red')">Select Red</button>
  <button (click)="selectBaseColor('green')">Select Green</button>
</div>

<!-- The result of answer will change function which is assigned to next buttons -->

<div name="question2">
  <button (click)="selectBrightness('light')">Select Light</button>
  <button (click)="selectBrightness('dark')">Select Dark</button>
</div>
```

App.component.ts:

```ts
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedBaseColor = null;
  selectedBrightness = null;

  selectBaseColor(color: string) {
    this.selectedBaseColor = color;
  }

  selectBrightness(brightness: string) {
    this.selectedBrightness = brightness;
  }
```

alternative following your style you dont need to change the function but its arguments:

```
<div name="question1">
  <button (click)="select('red')">Select Red</button>
  <button (click)="select('green')">Select Green</button>
</div>

<!-- The result of answer will change function which is assigned to next buttons -->

<div name="question2" [hidden]="isRed">
  <button (click)="select(isRed ? 'lightred' : 'lightgreen')">Select Light</button>
  <button (click)="select(isRed ? 'darkred' : 'darkgreen')">Select Dark</button>
</div>
```

If there are more colors than red and green, you should place the inline 'if' in your component.ts file.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem in this way:

```
 <div name="question1">
  <button (click)="select('red')">Select Red</button>
  <button (click)="select('green')">Select Green</button>
</div>

<div name="question2">
  <button #button1 id="button1" (click)="select(button1.name)">Select Light</button>
  <button #button2 id="button2" (click)="select(button2.name)">Select Dark</button>
</div>

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  select(color: string) {
  switch(color){
    case "red":
      document.getElementById("button1").setAttribute("name", "lightred");
      document.getElementById("button2").setAttribute("name", "darkred");
    case "green":
      document.getElementById("button1").setAttribute("name", "lightgreen");
      document.getElementById("button2").setAttribute("name", "darkgreen");
        }
    }
}
```